# How to set version format "1.1.1" (major.minor.patch) version in .netcore rest api

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, swagger, versioning

I need your help. I want to use nuget package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer for versioning of my aspnet core rest api.

Whole package looks great but I do not want to use default format Version Group.Major.Minor-Status but instead of that I want to have version format  major.minor.patch.

Example:
Instead of this url:
/api/v2015-05-01.3.0/foo
I want this url:
/api/v1.1.1/foo

The question is how to do it or is it possible ?

Thx so much

Comment: yeah but i want to use this format for example I do not want to have url : /api/v2015-05-01.3.0/foo but instead of that i want have url like /api/v1.1.1/foo

Comment: That's not `Major.Minor`. That's `random string.number.number`. Don't use *either*.

Comment: The purpose of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer` is to make it easy to work with the *de-facto* discoverability standard, Swagger (now OpenAPI). *Every client* expects the version to look a certain way. You already broke it when you used a string instead of a version number. Check the [Swagger versioning guidelines](https://app.swaggerhub.com/help/apis/versioning)

Comment: ok so when I want have version of my api as string.number.number. Is there option to use this nuget package for this purpose?

Comment: Read the [Swagger versioning guidelines](https://app.swaggerhub.com/help/apis/versioning). What you ask is *already* supported. What you posted in the question though has nothing to do with what you asked. Where did `v2015-05-01.3.0` come from? How did you configure this?

Comment: The [package's repo samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/tree/master/samples) show a *lot* of different ways to configure the version and route. One use [conventions](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/tree/master/samples/aspnetcore/ConventionsSample), another uses [attribute routing](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/blob/master/samples/aspnetcore/SwaggerSample/V3/Controllers/PeopleController.cs). What did you try?

Comment: Are you saying that you tried to use the `HasApiVersion` method or `ApiVersion` attribute and found it only accepst major/minor versions? Please, *you* have to provide enough information so people can help you. Don't force people to have to search just to understand what you are saying. `ApiExplorer ` *doesn't* add versioning. That's the job of the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning` package.

Comment: when  I use [ApiVersion("2.0.3")] attribute in my controller then I have exception by running.  An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
FormatException: The specified API version status '3' is invalid.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiVersion.Parse(string text)

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer is nuget package which contains all necessary stuff for using versioning in API. I am just using attribute ApiVersion which has constructor with string parameter. How I mentioned when I put there version format 1.1.1 then error occurred because the last number 1 is considered as state.. When i put there 1.1 then it works . So thats the reason why I am asking if there is option to customize versioning